# Possessive Pronouns Usage: Mine, Hers, His

Tags: pronouns, possessives, personal-pronouns

> **It's mine**

Which is simple and I can use it without any doubt anywhere. However, the below examples with "his" & "hers" are not that simple to me to use in my daily usage. I want to know how a native speaker would say this.

> **It's hers**
>
> **It's his**

Or is it mandatory to use the object name whenever we use "his", "her",....

> **It's her pen**
>
> **It's his pen**

**Question update to make it more clear:**

I'm not asking about difference or which one is correct. I'm just asking, as a native speaker would you say "It's his" in your daily conversation. Because, for a non native speaker like me, "It's his" without using object name doesn't sound good whenever I say it.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, because I am having trouble understanding how these are different to you. As long as the object you are referring to with "it" is clear, you can indicate its ownership with any of "it's mine," "it's hers," or "it's his." They are all the same. "Whose pen is this?" can be answered with any of them.

Comment: I'm not asking about difference or which one is correct. I'm just asking, as a native speaker would you say "its his" in your daily conversation. Because, for a non native speaker like me, "Its his" without using object name doesn't sound good whenever I say it.

Comment: Yes, I would say "it's mine," "it's hers", or "it's his" with the same regularity. To me, the grammatical structure is exactly the same, they all sound good, and none of them needs an object. Does that help?

Comment: Ok thanks, I just want to confirm it from a native English speaker.

Comment: @joiedevivre -- Your comments would make a good answer.

Comment: @joiedevivre And one more doubt, why do you use apostrophe in that sentence. If we are talking about possession of the Pronoun, we shouldn't use apostrophe as "Its", not "It's". Right?!!

Comment: The things we are talking about don't belong to "it." They belong to me, him, or her. "It's" is a contraction, here. It is mine. It is his. It is hers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After our exchange in the comments, I think what may be tripping you up is that "my" and "mine" sound so clearly different, but there's no difference in orthography or phonology between "his" and "his." But  these are both perfectly natural to native English speakers:

> It's his pen.
> It's his.

I'm not surprised if that feels strange to you if your language has different declensions for these cases, though!